# How to find assigned kafka consumers of a topic without a group id

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have some applications that directly consuming from Kafka using `assign(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` method in `KafkaConsumer`. They don't use `group.id` in Kafka. We would like to identify these consumers. Inside `KafkaAdminClient` there is a method `listConsumerGroups` which lists the consumers. But apparently, this method only lists the consumers using `subscribe` method and ignores the consumers using `assign` method. Is there a way of finding consumers using `assign` method?
Here is a sample code of the application:

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

import collection.JavaConverters._
import java.time.Duration
import java.util
object Test{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false")
    props.setProperty("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String,String](props)
    consumer.assign(List(new TopicPartition("test",3)).asJava)
   // consumer.subscribe(List("test").asJava)

    while(true){
      val buffer = new util.ArrayList[AnyRef]
      val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))
      import collection.JavaConverters._
      for (record <- records.asScala) {
        buffer.add(record)
      }
      if(buffer.size() > 0) {
        print(buffer)
        Thread.sleep(100)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you don't care about tracking offsets?

Comment: I think I didn't explain well. Assume the consumers track their offsets and that's usually true for the case of flink or spark structured streaming. But I don't have observability of those third-party applications' internal so I would like to track the applications consuming the data from that specific topics.

Comment: Well, your code here isn't using those, so how would it track? Spark does create a group id, though. Not sure about Flink